# List Element Configuration

Tags: python, list, variables, config, lookup

So I have a list where each element is associated with a variable(s). If the user wants to read a variable value I would need to take an element of the list perform my operation and then return it to the user. The list is ~250 elements, where each element is defined as a different variable. The element number and variable do not change.

Do I need some form of lookup table, or equivalent? Does it go in the main code, or can I keep it separate as a config file, i.e. txt file containing: element 1 = variable y

I'm fairly new to Python, so just want to pointed in the right direction really.

Comment: can you clarify what the elements in the list actually are with a short example

Comment: Is it possible that a dictionary is better ? A dictionary can associate a name with a value.

Comment: Sounds like you need a dictionary.

Comment: Elements are HEX bytes (e.g. 4f or d2). I'd be converting and returning, but the user needs to identify what they want look for, effectively the element numbers.

Comment: To calirify even more: Consider adding some (pseudp) code to your question, and what contents you would expect your config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure you seem to be wanting is a dictionary. Dictionaries allow you to reference elements by their key i.e. a key could be a "variable" and the value associated with the key is essentially data that can be referenced by the "variable". Dictionaries can be made by defining a variable as {} or by using the dict() function on something. I most often will do something like:

```
dictionary = dict(zip(list_of_names , list_of_data))
```

The lists could be made by reading your txt file and then using:

```
string.split("your delimiter here")
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll start reading into dictionaries. Appreciate it.